# The normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with degree a power of 2 is in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

In Galois theory I encountered the following question.

> Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $L$ be the normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Is $L \subset \mathbb{R}$ if $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ is a power of 2?

I don't know how to prove this. Can I have a proof?

Comment: It's hard (but regrettably not impossible) to prove things that are false!

Comment: Sorry there is a typo, I editted $[L:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] $ into $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$. How about in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: What happens if $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$?

Comment: In that case, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, \zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive 4-th root of unity, and $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=12$ not a power of 2. I don't understand why this can be a hint.

Comment: Think again about what a primitive 4th root of unity is.

Comment: I got it. $[L:\mathbb{Q}]= 8$ and $L$ is not in $\mathbb{R}$. It is a counterexample! Thank you!!

Comment: @Bae Instead of $\zeta$, you can call it by its usual name, $i$. :P